# What is the XPath to select a range of nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file that's structured like this:

```
 <foo>
     <bar></bar>
     <bar></bar>
     ...
</foo>
```

I don't know how to grab a range of nodes. Could someone give me an example of an XPath expression that grabs bar nodes 100-200?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short XPath expression selecting exactly the required nodes.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/bar[position() >= 100 and not(position() > 200)]
```

**Do note**:

1. Exactly the `bar` elements at position 100 to 200 (inclusive) are selected.
2. The evaluation of this XPath expressions can be many times faster than an expression using the `//` abbreviation, because the latter causes a complete scan of the tree whose root is the context node. **Always try to avoid using the `//` abbreviation** in cases when this is possible.

Comment: If you remember, could you go into your second point? Will // and /*/ return the same results, and yet still the latter is faster?

Comment: @BramVanroy,  Both `//` and `/*/` are syntactically invalid XPath expressions. I am guessing that you meant `//*` and /*/* . The answer is that in this specific case the time taken should be approximately the same. However, if predicates are involved, the expression including `//` will have to scan a whole tree (even the descendents of the finally selected nodes) and filter each node -- while in the case of the exact expression such scan is avoided. Do note also, that there are **some** XPath processors that are highly optimized to process `//*` and similar expressions efficiently.

Comment: @cbaldan The suggested edit is wrong, In fact the current text is correct: the XPath expression selects all intended items starting at position 100 and ending at position 200, and this is exactly what **_inclusive_** means.

Answer (score 12):

```
//foo/bar[100 <= position() and position() < 200]
```

Answer (score 9):

Isn't `fn:subsequence` the best way?

```
subsequence( /foo/bar, 100, 101 )
```

returns all items from position 100 through 200, that is 101 items (or less if the source sequence is shorter).

Comment: While this may be correct, the use of position() in a predicate is more general since it can be applied at multiple levels. E.g.: /foo/bar[2 <= position() and position() < 5]/x[5 <= position() and position() < 10]

Comment: @DonaldRich Yes – but that causes `position()` to be evaluated at every item in the sequence (which may be much more than those 100 items finally selected), while `subsequence()` is called just once. Anyway, this talk is about 'how can we select all nodes in the sequence at positions 100 through 200', and **not** about  'can we avoid using `position()` for every possible sequence filtering requirement?' My answer relates directly to — and just to — the question asked.

Comment: @DonaldRich BTW, provided we _have_ `subsequence()` available, your query can be easily rewritten as `subsequence( subsequence( /foo/bar, 2, 3)/x, 5, 5)`

Comment: CiaPan: the function `subsequence()` is defined in the W3c standard specification : "Functions and Operators" only from (XPath) ver. 2.0 and later. The OP is not probably using XPath 2.0, thus the solutions that use `position()` are more general -- work also in XPath 1.0 and using them gives us generality and universality so that we don't care about which version of XPath our environment is supporting.

Answer (score 1):

To select range, you must use position(), and use the clause 'and'. I'm going write two ways:

```
//foo//bar[position() >= 100 and position() <= 200]
```

or

```
//foo//bar[position() >= 100][position() <= 200]
```