# combining XPATH axes (preceding-sibling & following-sibling)

Tags: xpath, axes

Say I have the following UL:

```
<ul>
  <li>barry</li>
  <li>bob</li>
  <li>carl</li>
  <li>dave</li>
  <li>roger</li>
  <li>steve</li>
</ul>
```

I need to grab all the LIs between bob & roger. I can grab everything after bob with `//ul/li[contains(.,"bob")]/following-sibling::li`, and I can grab everything before roger with `//ul/li[contains(.,"roger")]/preceding-sibling::li`. The problem is when I try to combine the two, I end up getting extra results.

For example, `//ul/li[contains(.,"bob")]/following-sibling::li[contains(.,"roger")]/preceding-sibling::li` will of course get everything before roger, instead of ignoring the items before bob.

Is there a way to chain these two xpaths together?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354987/what-is-the-xpath-to-select-a-range-of-nodes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
/ul/li[preceding-sibling::li='bob' and following-sibling::li='roger']
```

Comment: Dastardly exploitation of the conversion rules. :)

Comment: @biziclop - Not sure what you mean. Do you mean the part where I do `li='bob'` or `li='roger'`? It could also be done like this: `/ul/li[preceding-sibling::li[.='bob'] and following-sibling::li[.='roger']]`. (`contains()` could also be used in those li predicates)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but I wasn't complaining, I was applauding.

Comment: @DanielHaley Hi, im using a file where the order of the siblings is not guranteed (they can be in any order). I see there is syntax for `preceeding-sibling` and `following-sibling` but is there syntax for `in-the-same-node-as-sibling-with-text` ?

Comment: @Jai - I'm not sure what you mean. I recommend creating a new question with a clear example.