# Set start position from XPath query

Tags: php, xml, xpath, position, limit

I try to get 5-10 values from XML

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath('//FILM');
```

Its posible set start position? example:

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath('//FILM[position() = 5 and position() = 10');
```

Comment: Check this post:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354987/what-is-the-xpath-to-select-a-range-of-nodes

Comment: You're almost there: you missed a `]` and entered an impossible logic expression (position can't be 5 and 10 at *same time* =) . `//FILM[position() > 5 and position() < 10]`