# XPath Syntax for conditions

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am in search of conditional XPath syntax. My xpath is as follows:

```
//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/input[1]
```

Now the scenario is that the above mentioned input field can be found at `tr[7]` (already mentioned) and `tr[6]`.
So in brief I need one syntax to test that the input field should be present either at tr[7] or tr[6]. i.e.:

```
//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/input[1]
//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/input[1]
```

Both the above mentioned XPath should be combined and the test should return true if the `input[1]` is present at either `tr[7]` or `tr[6]`.

PS: `tr[position()=7 or position()=6]` is not working. The code tries to find the element at lower position mentioned. i.e `tr[6]`

Comment: Are you sure that `tr[position()=7 or position()=6]` does not work? Please check, if there is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipeline syntax (|) here as below :

```
//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/input[1]|//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/input[1]
```

Comment: The `|` operator is the `union` operator not "pipeline syntax", see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-union.

Also you can shorten your expression by rewriting it to remove the common stem:
`//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/(tr[6] | tr[7])/td[2]/input[1]`

Answer (score 0):

the position method can be provided a range ...

```
tr[position() >= 6 and not(position() > 7)]
```

excerpt from [What is the xpath to select a range of nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354987/what-is-the-xpath-to-select-a-range-of-nodes)