# Python lxml print each table row

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

When I enter something in 'cn', script will make query on website and give me table with multiple rows

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XPath
import requests

cn = input ('CN: ')

find_page = requests.get('search query' + cn + '')
tree = html.fromstring(find_page.content)

# //tr[2]/td[2]/a/text() is first row after <th>
com = tree.xpath('//tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()')

print ('COM:', com)
```

This code print me only first row from table on XPath location //tr[2] but I need to print all other table rows `//tr[3]/td[2]/a/text()` `//tr[4]/td[2]/a/text()` `//tr[...]/td[2]/a/text()`

EDIT:

After solving to get all items from table, I have result for example `COM: ['DAP', 'DAPA', 'DAP FOOD']` all of this have href. I can access and scrape only on first link (DAP) but can't scrape from (DAPA and DAP FOOD)

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XPath
import requests

cn = input ('CN: ')

find_page = requests.get('search query' + cn + '')
tree = html.fromstring(find_page.content)
    
# //tr[2]/td[2]/a/text() is first row after <th>
com = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/text()')

link = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/@href')[0]
link = str(link)

com_link = ('website' + link)
page = requests.get(com_link)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

postal_code = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text()')[0]

print ('COM:', com)
print ('Postal Code', postal_code)
```

How can I access on DAP, DAPA, DAP FOOD and get postal_code from each?

Comment: use `all_rows = tree.xpath("//tr")` and `for`-loop `for row  in all_rows[1:]: row.xpath(".//td")`

Comment: or try without `[2]` but with slicing `[1:]` - `tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/text()')[1:]`

Comment: [What is the XPath to select a range of nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354987/what-is-the-xpath-to-select-a-range-of-nodes)

Comment: @furas ```tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/text()')[0:]``` working and give me all from table what I need, thank you.

Comment: why do you use `[0]` ?

Comment: @furas When not use ```[0]``` link is for example ```Link ['/folder/DAP']``` with and when I use with website it is like website['/folder/DAP'] So when use ```[0]``` it is website/folder/DAP

Comment: it only shows that your xpath `'//tr/td[2]/a/@href'` is ineffective because it should gives all links at once (similar to `'//tr/td[2]/a/text()'`). And it can means you may have to do it in different way - like in my first comment - first find all rows and later search text, link, postcode in every row separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

Changed `com = tree.xpath('//tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()')` to `com = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/text()')` and it working

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XPath
import requests

cn = input ('CN: ')

find_page = requests.get('search query' + cn + '')
tree = html.fromstring(find_page.content)

# //tr[2]/td[2]/a/text() is first row after <th>
com = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/text()')

print ('COM:', com)
```

Comment: you should get the same result without `[0:]`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It working without [0:]

Comment: @furas I have edited on first question, if you can check and know how to solve it.

Comment: why do you use `[0]` in links ? Without `[0]` you should get all values.